# How can I get the ApplicationContext from a Kotlin bean definition file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

In a kotlin bean definition file I need to get the `ApplicationContext`, so I can inject it in another bean.

There's obviously no documentation on how to do that. `env` returns the `ConfigurableEnvironment` from `GenericApplicationContext`(`ApplicationContext`), but I don't gain direct access to the context itself.

beans {

```
...

bean<PantryService> {
    PantryServiceImpl(ref(), ref(), ref(), ref(), ref(), ref(), ref())
}

...
```

}

the last argument needs to be the `ApplicationContext`

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of the bean definition file?

Comment: Where you call registerBean `this` will refer to the application context.

Comment: @k0enf0rNL done